# Is this an example of dead code / Duplicate code / Temporary Field?

Tags: java

I came across the below snippet. But I do not understand if it an example of **dead code / duplicate code / temporary field?**

```
public class InterestRateComputer {
    public double interest (double amount) {
        double interest = 0;
        if (balance > MIN_BALANCE) {
            //compute the regular interest
            return interest;
        }else {
            //compute interest for below min balance
            return interest;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: use indentation

Comment: Do you know what any of the mentioned things mean? Do you know what dead code *is*, what duplicate code would be, what a temporary field might be??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't even compile. Java does not usually allow dead code if its (very basic) analysis shows that there is dead code *AND* a boolean constant isn't involved (complicated, silly reasons for that last rule). Except, in java, this is more generally called 'unreachable code' (it means the same thing as 'dead code', but that's the term usually used, and what the compiler will be mentioning as it refuses to compile this).

"Temporary Field"? No idea what that's about - it is certainly completely unrelated to the concept of dead code.

It's not duplicate code - duplicate code is not something in any specification. When used without further context, it generally means the notion that somebody's been copy/pasting code all over the place. It works fine, but it's annoying: If there is a bug in this code, you now have to fix it in 50 places, for example (there are more reasons it's a bad idea to copy/paste code all over. Instead, put the code in a library, utility method, or class - and then have all places where you wanted to paste it to use this library/utility/class).